# Why does app go to the create.html.erb view after post submission instead of show.html.erb view? rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

Right now in my rails 4 app after the user submits a post I want the app to redirect/render the show view, but right now it just goes to the create view.  Here is my Posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id]) # show
  end
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:Title, :Body) #whatsoever your post has
  end

#redirect_to post_path(@post)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post.find(params[:id])
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root :to => "pages#index"
devise_for :users
resources :users
resources :pages
resources :posts
end
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your `end` is in wrong place. Also `permit(:title, :body)` should starts with lowercase letters.

Comment: Conventionally params aren't capitalized (`params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)`). Are you sure your `@post` is saving correctly? I'm not sure that `post_params` works if you try calling it before you `def` it inside the method…

Comment: Yeah I realize they shouldn't be capitalized but I made the mistake a couple times before I noticed so I just went with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a few bits of code in wrong places - `end` statements, and your final `if` statement at the bottom, which doesn't seem to be in any method.

Something like this should work:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id]) # show
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post.find(params[:id])
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body) #whatsoever your post has
  end

end
```

Comment: I tried this and I get this error: 
NoMethodError at /posts/23

undefined method `each' for #<Post:0x000000063a8f08>

Answer (score 0):

First, the redirect is wrong. It should be simply:

```
redirect_to @post
```

After fixing that, it could be re-rendering because there was an error validating the `@post`. If `@post.save` fails the form will be re-rendered, but the URL will stay pointed at the create action.